# How to fix label contour lines layer displays on top of all layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

How can I fix the situation, when the label contour lines  displays (on top of all layers) on top of this layer?

QGIS 2.15.0-Master
[image]

[image: contour lines layer displays on top of all layers]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question for clarity. Are your contour labels in a separate layer than the contours and showing on top of all other layers (my understanding of this question)? Have you tried either turning off this annotation layer or moving it down in the table of contents so the drawing order is different?

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. Іn the future will be more accurately formulate the question.
I generated a vector layer and raster contours of a label used importance elevation.
But the label is displayed on top of all layers. I want to disable it, or tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option where you use a feature as an obstacle to discourage labeling other features if they are overlapping each other. But as far as I know, it just shift the labels of one layer if they are overlapped by another layer. For example in your case you want to prevent contour lines to be labeled when they are covered by "New scratch layer". So you can label the contour line as usual, and use the "New scratch layer" as an obstacle by going to `layer properties -> Labels -> and from the drop down menu select 'Discourage other labels from covering features in this layer'`, as you can see below

[image]

I am not sure if it will be successful in your case or not, but you can give it a try.

You can check [ndawson answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175715/63384), who is the developer of the tool, and for more details check [here](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/07/recent-labelling-improvements-in-qgis-master/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but does not help. The more I go deep, so it is not clear. I'm not a beginner, but I can not fix the problem and find a solution.
[screenshot](http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/16/0419/h_1461073449_8621012_2d930b1048.jpeg)