# QGIS - Use one layer to block another layers labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have two layers, one with points that I have set a label on and another with polygons which I would like to use to block the labeling of the points. According to this [old answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175715/68885) to [Avoiding labeling features if overlapped by another layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175697) I could use the blocking of labeling option of the polygon layer, but this only works partially.

With "No labels":

[image: No labels]

With "Blocking":

[image: Blocking]

Is this a bug or have I understood the option of "Blocking" wrong? (What other option than remove the points under the polygon do I have?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to block completely (hide) the labels under the polygon, you can use the following formula under point label tab -> Render -> Show label -> Edit, and write the following expression:

[image]

```
case
when intersection( $geometry, geometry(get_feature( 'PolyBlock', 'id',0))) then 0
else 1
end
```

Where `'PolyBlock'` is the name of the polygon layer in the layer tree, and `'id' equal 0` is the id field which has the value 0 or the value exists for the target polygon, which you want to use it to hide the labels of the points.

Here is the results

[image]