# How to display a label from another layer (without creating a new layer)?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

Layer A contains terrains knowing that the geometries have been merged when they are contiguous 'and' the owners are identical.
The layer includes a variable indicating the number of slots.
[image]

[image]

Layer B contains the lands and a variable indicating the type of owner (the lands are not merged as in layer A).

[image]

I am displaying layer B with only owner type 'FF'.

[image]

I seek to recover in layer A, the number of corresponding housing. (Here 8 et 26 uniquely)

[image]

If polygon FF of layer B contains 1 terrain, there will be a label.

If polygon FF of layer B contains several contiguous terrains, there will be more identical labels (I will then see how to retain only one).

I tried without success to apply a display rule in the labels of layer B:

```
CASE WHEN owner = 'FF' and intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature('Layer_A','nlogh', nlogh))) THEN nlogh END
```

I don't know how to retrieve the values

Comment: Are you asking how to `join attributes by location`?

Comment: This command allows you to select objects by location. However, I want to display for some objects of layer B, the corresponding labels of layer A. There is therefore a question of localization but also of filter without creating a new layer. In addition I specify that I have my diapers are bulky: layer A : 594035 geometry
layer B : 1334777 geometry and i want a display instantaneous...

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Erik  It's done

Comment: How does the geometry for Layer A correspond with Layer B, are the polygons the same, overlapping, ... etc? Perhaps add another screenshot showing Layer A too, it will make your question clearer.

Comment: @Matt  It's done

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/424303/128665

Comment: @Matt Thank you this does not answer my problem but it is very interesting.
These functions display labels differently depending on the scale.

Comment: I found a link on the subject  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374322/qgis-use-one-layer-to-block-another-layers-labels