# Preventing labels from overlapping certain features using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

I have two layers in my QGIS Project (QGIS 3.4.8). One in the foreground, which contains surfaces, and one in the background, which contains a point with labels, see image below:

[image]

The problem is that the labels from the second layer are always in the foreground:

[image]

I would like the second layer's label to be displayed in the background, just like the layer itself.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Desired target result (image edited with MS Paint):

[image]

Comment: "Why on earth would you wanna do that?!" cries the cartographer.

Comment: Don't worry. I have a more complicated project where it makes sense. Here I am just asking if it works in QGIS.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230671/symbols-above-labels-in-map-qgis/230684

Comment: And this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175697/avoiding-labeling-features-if-overlapped-by-another-layer-in-qgis

Answer (score 9):

**Using QGIS 3.16.0**

Assuming your labels are stored in `"name"` field, go to `Layer Properties > Labels` and set the labeling expression as below:

```
if(overlay_disjoint('area'), "name", "")
```

[image]

More information about `overlay_disjoint()` function, please find in [Changelog for QGIS 3.16](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) and [QGIS Docs » List of functions » overlay_disjoint](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-disjoint).

Comment: Would probably be possible using older QGIS versions with either `overlaps` or `disjoint` and some `aggregate`-wizardry.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar question, and I find a solution. I don't know if this can help:

- find the label style of the polygon feature.
- set it as "blocking"
  [image]