# VectorTiles Basemap labels over other layer geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, vector-tiles, basemap

VectorTiles Basemap (OSM host) labels are displayed above all other layer features geometries in QGIS, regardless of the layer order in the layers panel. In other words, even if the vector tiles basemap is positioned as the lowest layer in layers panel, labels are displayed at the top of other features. Can this be adjusted (similar to XYZ Tiles in QGIS)?

[image]

Comment: check out this question - there are 2 good solutions in the answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/379413/176374