# Aggregate Lines Based on Distance between Segments

Tags: line, linux, vector-tiles, aggregation, optimization

I have a [VectorTile](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/) basemap that I am optimizing, (working on reducing the size of individual tiles), the major chunk of tile size is road data (geometry and attributes). I am working on simplifying the individual road geometries based on the [Zoom Level](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels), and aggregating the roads based on zoom levels as well.

The roads are stored in a Postgis table ( individual table for each zoom level ) and I want to aggregate the roads based on the zoom level they will be displayed at. For example, In the Zoom Level 5 table I want to aggregate the roads that are within a certain distance of one another, and make a single line for the road segments:
[image]

Since it is not possible to make out individual roads at that zoom level:
[image]

How can I aggregate the road geometries based on the distance between road segments?

*PS: I am working on PostGIS and QGIS on Linux, but I am open to solutions using any Open Source platform or technology*

Comment: Do the roads have a common ID e.g. two lanes at zoom level 5 on the A50 is represented by two lines, but at level 4 by one lin and they all have "A50" as their attribute?

Comment: They are represented by two lines at all zoom levels. They highways and motorways will have the common attribute like "M-2" for the Motorways.

Answer (score 5):

You could try looking int this OS option, [Skeletron](https://github.com/migurski/Skeletron), it:

> generalizes collections of lines to a specific spherical mercator
>   zoom level and pixel precision, using a polygon buffer and voronoi diagram
>
> It is based off of [a 1996 paper by Alnoor Ladak and Roberto B. Martinez, "Automated
>   Derivation of High Accuracy Road Centrelines Thiessen Polygons Technique"](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc96/TO400/PAP370/P370.HTM)

There are some dependecies required:

Required dependencies:
  - qhull binary (http://www.qhull.org)
  - shapely 1.2+ (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)
  - pyproj (http://code.google.com/p/pyproj)
  - networkx 1.5+ (http://networkx.lanl.gov)
  - StreetNames 0.1+ (https://github.com/nvkelso/map-label-style-manual/tree/master/tools/street_names)

*Note: This is an older model/tool that can be applied, just as a reference for you to explore.*

Comment: I think skeletron could be the way to go, but your reply is juste a copy past of the readme file and the link to the esri website is dead. Here a link 
to show what it does for maps : https://kartographie.geo.tu-dresden.de/downloads/ica-gen/workshop2004/Haunert-v2-ICAWorkshop.pdf. that look really great but when I try to use it I didnot known how to use it. I didnot found a documentation except some bribes with the use or setup.py --help command ... If someone explain how use that lib I give him the bounty.

Comment: Also it uses OSM roads as in input as far as I can see, I want a solution that can work on any type of line. Still, I really love the science behind it, would love to apply this to other scenarios as well.

Comment: I've updated my posted to reflect your comments, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

ArcGIS is the simplest if it is at all an option. I know the OP specifies OS but I mention this as the OS options just don't look very helpful compared to :
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Merge_Divided_Roads/00700000000w000000/

Answers to this question give some Open Source options : [How can I merge/collapse nearby and parallel road lines (eg. a dual-carriageway) into one single line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/how-can-i-merge-collapse-nearby-and-parallel-road-lines-eg-a-dual-carriageway)

If you code you could calculate the mean coordinate position on a vertex basis,   if not then:

1. buffer the roads with a "merge all" option on the output.
2. Get the centre line of the polygon
3. Split the lines at junctions with JUMP  [Split Lines at Intersection of Other Lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98087/split-lines-at-intersection-of-other-lines)
4. Spatial Join the attributes back on

There doesn't seem to be a good OS equivalent to ArcGIS 'Polygon to Centre line' tool either. I might suggest :

a. Create voronoi diagram and take the skeleton.
b. Create a Euclidean distance raster and extract the central value and convert to a line

... probably some others as well.

Finally, depending on the scale and application.. it might also be worth just deleting one of the two lines - will the imprecision matter?

Comment: The ArcGIS option looks good, I will give it a shot, but I would prefer an OS solution. 

Calculating the mean coordinate position on a vertex basis, is my fall-back strategy.

I will try all the methods you have listed and see if they work for me, thanks!

Comment: The ArcGIS tool, ' Merge Divided Roads (Cartography) ', is exactly what I am looking for, but all the processing I am doing is on Linux, using Postgres and QGIS, to use the tool I will need to make the switch to windows.